# browser won´t take the settings for new div´s

Tags: html, css, browser

I am programming CSS for a symfony2 project. This project is already far programmed.

Now I added some div´s and a table. The table I can design more or less, but when I create new div´s and want to set these like:

```
div {
    background: #f00;
    color: #eee;
}
```

The browser shows nothing about these settings. They are shown in the HTML of the Browser but are totally not setted.

Comment: try adding `!important` to your style..see if that makes any changes to your website..so do it as `div {
    background: #f00 !important;
    color: #eee !important;
}`

Comment: 99.9999% chance your selector isn't as specific as the one that's getting applied to the element. CSS Specificity is one of the first things you need to learn about CSS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Try to add height to your div when there is no content in it.

Comment: @Lal '!important' helps not

Comment: @Christian yeah i know that, i even couldn´t set a div in html the browser shows nothing in firefox and chrome

Comment: ok new information.
i described few divs twice at the end of css and then it takes the settings. what is totally not understandable.....

Comment: it was a long day i quit ......

Comment: What if you give your div's a _unique_ class name and set the css rules on the very same class? ... and make sure you do a full reset of the div's properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stupid mistake in css.

I made a comment before the first rule with two slashes:

```
//comment
.rule {
    property: value;
}
```

which made probably skip the next rule and the browser didn´t rendered it as code. so just edited the comment from two slashes to `/* comment */` and everything is good.